# How to annotate existing class at compile time?

Tags: java, maven, ant, annotations

I need to annotate an existing class like this:

```
package com.example;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

public class AnnotateMe { 
    public String method1() { return ""; }  
    public int method2() { return 0; }  
    public void method3() { }   
}
```

Adding `@WebService` and `@WebMethod` at compile time to achieve this output:

```
package com.example;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class AnnotateMe { 
    @WebMethod
    public String method1() { return ""; }  
    @WebMethod
    public int method2() { return 0; }  
    @WebMethod
    public void method3() { }   
}
```

I need to annotate each class method, without distinction.

Is possible with an Ant or Maven task?